# Ubuntu 14.04でL2TP/IPsecのVPN接続ができない

Tags: network, ubuntu

Ubuntu 14.04でL2TP/IPsecのVPN接続をl2tp-ipsec-vpnでしているのですが、うまくいきません

[Linux から L2TP/IPsec で VPN](http://blog.hktechno.net/2013/02/linux-l2tpipsec-vpn.html)
を見て設定しました

VPNのサーバーへはWindowsやAndroidからはつながるのですが、Ubuntuだけつながりません

インストールされてるバージョンです
l2tp-ipsec-vpn: 1.0.9-1
openswan: 1:2.6.38-1
ppp: 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2

ログは以下の通りです
接続先のIPをxx.xx.xx.xxに置き換えています

syslog

```
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Opening client connection
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Opening client connection
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Closing client connection
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec setup start
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 kernel: [ 5120.551126] NET: Registered protocol family 15
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec U2.6.38/K3.13.0-55-generic...
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 ipsec_setup: Using NETKEY(XFRM) stack
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 kernel: [ 5120.645493] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec started
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec setup start finished with exit code 0
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command service xl2tpd start
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31680]: setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31680]: This binary does not support kernel L2TP.
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.6 started on user-x240 PID:31683
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command service xl2tpd start finished with exit code 0
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "vpntest"
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec auto --ready
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --ready finished with exit code 0
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec auto --up vpntest
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Closing client connection
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --up vpntest finished with error code 93
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --up vpntest finished with exit code 0
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Opening client connection
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command service xl2tpd stop
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 xl2tpd[31683]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command service xl2tpd stop finished with exit code 0
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec setup stop
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 ipsec_setup: Stopping Openswan IPsec...
Jun 23 09:20:11 user-x240 kernel: [ 5201.856486] NET: Unregistered protocol family 15
Jun 23 09:20:11 user-x240 ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec stopped
Jun 23 09:20:11 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec setup stop finished with exit code 0
Jun 23 09:20:11 user-x240 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Closing client connection
```

auth.log

```
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 ipsec__plutorun: Starting Pluto subsystem...
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: Starting Pluto (Openswan Version 2.6.38; Vendor ID OEvy\134kgzWq\134s) pid:31665
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: LEAK_DETECTIVE support [disabled]
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: OCF support for IKE [disabled]
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: SAref support [disabled]: Protocol not available
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: SAbind support [disabled]: Protocol not available
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: NSS support [disabled]
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: HAVE_STATSD notification support not compiled in
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: Setting NAT-Traversal port-4500 floating to on
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]:    port floating activation criteria nat_t=1/port_float=1
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]:    NAT-Traversal support  [enabled]
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: using /dev/urandom as source of random entropy
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating OAKLEY_AES_CBC: Ok (ret=0)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_hash(): Activating OAKLEY_SHA2_512: Ok (ret=0)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_hash(): Activating OAKLEY_SHA2_256: Ok (ret=0)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: starting up 3 cryptographic helpers
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: started helper pid=31671 (fd:6)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: started helper pid=31672 (fd:7)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31671]: using /dev/urandom as source of random entropy
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: started helper pid=31673 (fd:8)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: Using Linux 2.6 IPsec interface code on 3.13.0-55-generic (experimental code)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31672]: using /dev/urandom as source of random entropy
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31673]: using /dev/urandom as source of random entropy
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_ccm_8: Ok (ret=0)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_ccm_12: FAILED (ret=-17)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_ccm_16: FAILED (ret=-17)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_gcm_8: FAILED (ret=-17)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_gcm_12: FAILED (ret=-17)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_gcm_16: FAILED (ret=-17)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: added connection description "vpntest"
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: listening for IKE messages
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface wlan0/wlan0 192.168.24.54:500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface wlan0/wlan0 192.168.24.54:4500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:4500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface wlan0/wlan0 2001:a033:6c71:0:591e:8386:990a:5d43:500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface wlan0/wlan0 2001:a033:6c71:0:eab1:fcff:feab:1aad:500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: adding interface lo/lo ::1:500
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: listening for IKE messages
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: forgetting secrets
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: initiating Main Mode
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=115 
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: enabling possible NAT-traversal with method RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal)
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I1 to state STATE_MAIN_I2
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike (MacOS X): i am NATed
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I2 to state STATE_MAIN_I3
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: Main mode peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '192.168.100.1'
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: we require peer to have ID 'xx.xx.xx.xx', but peer declares '192.168.100.1'
Jun 23 09:18:50 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: sending encrypted notification INVALID_ID_INFORMATION to xx.xx.xx.xx:4500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: forgetting secrets
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest": deleting connection
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: "vpntest" #1: deleting state (STATE_MAIN_I3)
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface lo/lo ::1:500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface wlan0/wlan0 2001:a033:6c71:0:eab1:fcff:feab:1aad:500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface wlan0/wlan0 2001:a033:6c71:0:591e:8386:990a:5d43:500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:4500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface wlan0/wlan0 192.168.24.54:4500
Jun 23 09:20:10 user-x240 pluto[31665]: shutting down interface wlan0/wlan0 192.168.24.54:500
```

いろいろ試したのですが、解決できてません
なにか分かる方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか